# phpstorm configuration for laravel, phalcon or codeigniter?

Tags: php, web, frameworks, phpstorm

How do I configure PHPStorm autocomplete to framework codeignitir 3 and others, for example to call methods or function with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>?

Comment: Add ide stubs for phalcon here https://github.com/gsouf/phalcon-stubs

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be necessary for frameworks like Laravel or CodeIgniter, since their code should already be included in your PhpStorm project (and thus accessible to the IDE to facilitate code navigation/auto-completion/etc.).

However, since Phalcon is a PHP extension, you'll need to download its plaintext source files and include them as an external library in your PhpStorm project.  To do this, clone the https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools.git repository into a folder outside of your main project folder.  Let's call that folder "phalcon-devtools".  Then from within your IDE:  `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Include Path > Add new > Specify other` and choose the proper subfolder corresponding to the version of Phalcon you're using.  (For example, `phalcon-devtools/ide/2.0.5`).